# Directx 12 Vertex buffer/shader question

Tags: directx12

Is there a way to process individual vertex that get pumped into the vertex shader.

I have a cube and pyramid.

I want to multiply a different world*view*proj matrix for the cube. So the first 8 vertex should be a differtent matrix.

Is is possible to do such a thing in the vertex shader?

Comment: Use the world transformation matrix so that the box and pyramid are disjoint in world space.

Luna, Frank D. Introduction To 3D Game Programming With Direct X 12 . Mercury Learning and Information. Kindle Edition.

Comment: DirectX 12 can do the same thing as DirectX 11 with respect to vertex processing, it just drives the hardware in different ways. DirectX12 is an expert graphics API and is quite unforgiving. Focus on learning DirectX 11 first, and you'll probably find it's more than enough for what you are doing. Don't try to learn DirectX 12 first.

Answer (score 1):

In Shader Model 5.1 (required for DirectX 12), you certainly could use `SV_VertexID` in the vertex shader to address different matrices in your constant buffer(s) to transform some of the vertices uniquely, but it's unlikely that in your case the performance difference would be worth the complexity. Unless you are drawing millions of these things, you'd be better off just having distinct vertices for the two shapes: A simple no-branching shader that doesn't need system-generated values is going to be faster than a complex, dynamic branching shader that requires extra information, so the extra vertex count isn't a problem in practice.

See [Using System-Generated Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205118.aspx)

> `SV_VertexID` is also supported in Shadel Model 4 or later so you can use it with DirectX 11 with Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 10.0 or later. It's not supported for Direct3D Hardware Feature Levels 9.1, 9.2, or 9.3.